# Big performance issue on startup using myfaces 2.0 with tomcat 6

Tags: performance, jsf-2, startup, tomcat7, myfaces

I am having trouble on tomcat 6 startup. When I first try to load a page it takes more than five minutes to show it. After that it works perfectly fine.

Using the helloworld-example from myfaces the server answered as fast as you'd expect it to.
After adding a simple session scoped object and renaming the initial helloworld.xhtml the
server started to take very long during startup.

The full startup log is as follows:

```
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start
Information: Starting tomcat server
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
Information: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:25 AM org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider getStandardFacesConfig
Information: Reading standard config META-INF/standard-faces-config.xml
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider getWebAppFacesConfig
Information: Reading config /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.config.LogMetaInfUtils logArtifact
Information: Artifact 'myfaces-api' was found in version '2.1.8' from path 'file:/E:/Users/Andreas/Dropbox/Studium/4.Semester/Software-Projekt/Marx1/trunk/deliverable3/parent/webui/target/webui-0.0.1/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-api-2.1.8.jar'
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.config.LogMetaInfUtils logArtifact
Information: Artifact 'myfaces-impl' was found in version '2.1.8' from path 'file:/E:/Users/Andreas/Dropbox/Studium/4.Semester/Software-Projekt/Marx1/trunk/deliverable3/parent/webui/target/webui-0.0.1/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-impl-2.1.8.jar'
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.util.ExternalSpecifications isBeanValidationAvailable
Information: MyFaces Bean Validation support disabled
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator handleSerialFactory
Information: Serialization provider : class org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.serial.DefaultSerialFactory
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.DefaultLifecycleProviderFactory getLifecycleProvider
Information: Using LifecycleProvider org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.AllAnnotationLifecycleProvider
2012-07-03 03:43:26 WebuiConfiguration [INFO] Loading application wide configuration.
2012-07-03 03:43:26 ConfigurationMonitor [INFO] Trying to init. default config file.
E:\Users\Andreas\veryfive\config.xml
2012-07-03 03:43:26 XMLJFigParser [INFO] Process file E:\Users\Andreas\veryfive\config.xml
2012-07-03 03:43:26 ConfigurationMonitor [INFO] Intitialized configuration: E:\Users\Andreas\veryfive\config.xml
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer initFaces
Information: ServletContext initialized.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: Tomahawk jar not available. Autoscrolling, DetectJavascript, AddResourceClass and CheckExtensionsFilter are disabled now.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: Scanning for context init parameters not defined. It is not necessary to define them all into your web.xml, they are just provided here for informative purposes. To disable this messages set org.apache.myfaces.LOG_WEB_CONTEXT_PARAMS config param to 'false'
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.RESOURCE_EXCLUDES' found, using default value '.class .jsp .jspx .properties .xhtml .groovy'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING' found, using default value 'true (false with 1.2 webapps)'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX' found, using default value '.xhtml .view.xml .jsp'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.FACELETS_SUFFIX' found, using default value '.xhtml'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.HONOR_CURRENT_COMPONENT_ATTRIBUTES' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS' found, using default value 'auto'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.ENUM_CONVERTER_ALLOW_STRING_PASSTROUGH' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.validator.DISABLE_DEFAULT_BEAN_VALIDATOR' found, using default value 'true'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.LIFECYCLE_ID' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLER' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.CHECKED_VIEWID_CACHE_SIZE' found, using default value '500'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.CHECKED_VIEWID_CACHE_ENABLED' found, using default value 'true'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML' found, using default value 'true'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT' found, using default value 'true'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.CONFIG_REFRESH_PERIOD' found, using default value '2'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.VIEWSTATE_JAVASCRIPT' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_VIEWSTATE_ID' found, using default value 'true'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.STRICT_XHTML_LINKS' found, using default value 'true'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_CLEAR_JAVASCRIPT_FOR_BUTTON' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_HIDDEN_FIELDS_FOR_LINK_PARAMS' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.SAVE_FORM_SUBMIT_LINK_IE' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.DELEGATE_FACES_SERVLET' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.REFRESH_TRANSIENT_BUILD_ON_PSS' found, using default value 'auto'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.VALIDATE_XML' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.WRAP_SCRIPT_CONTENT_WITH_XML_COMMENT_TAG' found, using default value 'true'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_FORM_SUBMIT_SCRIPT_INLINE' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.DEBUG_PHASE_LISTENER' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.STRICT_JSF_2_REFRESH_TARGET_AJAX' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.STRICT_JSF_2_CC_EL_RESOLVER' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.DEFAULT_RESPONSE_WRITER_CONTENT_TYPE_MODE' found, using default value 'text/html'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.VIEW_UNIQUE_IDS_CACHE_ENABLED' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.COMPONENT_UNIQUE_IDS_CACHE_SIZE' found, using default value '100'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.SUPPORT_JSP_AND_FACES_EL' found, using default value 'true'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.FLASH_SCOPE_DISABLED' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_MAX_TIME_EXPIRES' found, using default value '604800000'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_HANDLER_CACHE_SIZE' found, using default value '500'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_HANDLER_CACHE_ENABLED' found, using default value 'true'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.USE_ENCRYPTION' found, using default value 'true'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.SECRET' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.ALGORITHM' found, using default value 'DES'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.SECRET.CACHE' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.ALGORITHM.IV' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.ALGORITHM.PARAMETERS' found, using default value 'ECB/PKCS5Padding'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.SERIAL_FACTORY' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.COMPRESS_STATE_IN_CLIENT' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.MAC_ALGORITHM' found, using default value 'HmacSHA1'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.MAC_SECRET' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.MAC_SECRET.CACHE' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.LAZY_LOAD_CONFIG_OBJECTS' found, using default value 'true'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.STRICT_JSF_2_ALLOW_SLASH_LIBRARY_NAME' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.VALIDATE' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.LifecycleProvider' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.EL_RESOLVER_COMPARATOR' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.EL_RESOLVER_PREDICATE' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.CHECKED_VIEWID_CACHE_SIZE' found, using default value '500'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.CHECKED_VIEWID_CACHE_ENABLED' found, using default value 'true'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_TEMPLATE_RESOURCE' found, using default value 'META-INF/rsc/myfaces-dev-error.xml'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.DEBUG_TEMPLATE_RESOURCE' found, using default value 'META-INF/rsc/myfaces-dev-debug.xml'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING' found, using default value 'false, on Development Project stage: true'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_SEQUENTIAL_VIEWS_IN_SESSION' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.CACHE_OLD_VIEWS_IN_SESSION_MODE' found, using default value 'off'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.USE_FLASH_SCOPE_PURGE_VIEWS_IN_SESSION' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.HANDLE_STATE_CACHING_MECHANICS' found, using default value 'true'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.USE_MULTIPLE_JS_FILES_FOR_JSF_UNCOMPRESSED_JS' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.JSF_JS_MODE' found, using default value 'normal'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.SERVICE_PROVIDER_FINDER' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.SAVE_STATE_WITH_VISIT_TREE_ON_PSS' found, using default value 'true'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.CHECK_ID_PRODUCTION_MODE' found, using default value 'auto'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'facelets.BUFFER_SIZE' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.FACELETS_DECORATORS' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'facelets.DECORATORS' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'facelets.LIBRARIES' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD' found, using default value '-1'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD' found, using default value '-1'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.FACELETS_RESOURCE_RESOLVER' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'facelets.RESOURCE_RESOLVER' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.MARK_INITIAL_STATE_WHEN_APPLY_BUILD_VIEW' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.WRAP_TAG_EXCEPTIONS_AS_CONTEXT_AWARE' found, using default value 'true'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.CACHE_EL_EXPRESSIONS' found, using default value 'noCache'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.INITIALIZE_ALWAYS_STANDALONE' found, using default value 'false'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.LOG_WEB_CONTEXT_PARAMS' found, using default value 'auto'.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.FACES_INITIALIZER' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger logWebContextParams
Information: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.FACES_INIT_PLUGINS' found.
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer initFaces
Warnung: 

*******************************************************************
*** WARNING: Apache MyFaces-2 is running in DEVELOPMENT mode.   ***
***                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^         ***
*** Do NOT deploy to your live server(s) without changing this. ***
*** See Application#getProjectStage() for more information.     ***
*******************************************************************

Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
Information: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jul 03, 2012 3:43:26 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
Information: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

After calling the page these two lines are added (after the page is rendered, which takes sometime as you can see in the log):

```
Jul 03, 2012 3:45:30 AM org.apache.myfaces.util.ExternalSpecifications isUnifiedELAvailable
Information: MyFaces Unified EL support disabled
```

Comment: Your logs show "Information: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29" and you have specified that you are using Tomcat 7???

Comment: It is probably more related to your particular environment than to MyFaces. No evidence of a problem so far.

Comment: Ah I am sorry, I am using the tomcat7-maven-plugin not tomcat 7. I edited the original post.

Ok there is no problem in the log so far. But what would the next thing to look at be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can get rid of the last two lines, for that you need to enable MyFaces EL Support to Tomcat 6 by adding el-api-2.2 and el-impl-2.2 jars. Here is a detailed procedure. [Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/HowToEnableEl22).

After that you can follow some of the tips mentioned here:

- [Decreasing Tomcat Startup Time](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/DecreasingTomcatStartupTimeWithMultiThreading)
- [Performance tuning JVM running tomcat](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/11/22/performance-tuning-jvm-running-tomcat)

Comment: I am using maven and the tomcat7-maven-plugin. How can I provide the plugin with the jars? Or should I just add them as dependencies?

Comment: oh that documentation specifies for Jetty also, just add them as dependencies that should be good enough.

Comment: Well the steps I took actually made the startup time much shorter. However, it seems that the first page call has nothing to do with the startup. It just takes ages, though tomcat itself already runs..